# Expat c library XML schema validation

Tags: xml, libxml2, expat-parser

Does [Expat]https://libexpat.github.io/ c library parser can do the XML data validation against XML Schema Definition(XSD) like library `Libxml2`?

Many thx!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, expat only offers an event-based, stream-oriented XML parser.